# How to add User-Defined arguments to command in system()?

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am working on a project, that needs to execute a command (glow) with an argument that the user entered.

Currently using this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                                                                        
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                         
int main() {
   char argument[100];                                                                                                                
   fgets(argument, 100, stdin);                                                                                                       
   system("glow %s", argument);                                                                                                       
   return 0;
}
```

And when I compile this, I get "error: too many arguments to function call, expected 1, have 2
system("glow %s", argument);"

Comment: Know that what you're doing is unsafe. Consider user input `;reboot` or `; rm -rf /` or `foo & deltree c:\windows`

Comment: use `system(argument);` - this will do what you want.